# Solution of a system of differential equations seems wrong with sympy

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to evaluate sympy for the solution of differential equations. As a simple example I have examined radioactive decay:

```
from sympy import *
N1,N2 = symbols('N1 N2', cls=Function)
l1,l2,t,N0 = symbols('l1 l2 t N0')
dlg1 = Eq(N1(t).diff(t),-l1*N1(t))
dlg2 = Eq(N2(t).diff(t),-l2*N2(t) + l1*N1(t))
ics = {N1(0):N0, N2(0):0} 
dsolve([dlg2,dlg1],[N2(t),N1(t)],ics=ics)
```

The result is:

```
[Eq(N2(t), N0*l1*exp(-l2*t)/(l1 - l2) - N0*l1*exp(-l1*t)/(l1 - l2)),
 Eq(N1(t), N0*exp(-l1*t))]
```

While N1(t) is correct N2(t) seems wrong, l1 and l2 should change places.

If I try the same with maxima:

```
eq_1: 'diff(N1(t),t) = -l1*N1(t);
eq_2: 'diff(N2(t),t) = -l2*N2(t)+l1*N1(t);
atvalue(N1(t),t=0,N0);
atvalue(N2(t),t=0,0);
sol: desolve([eq_1, eq_2],[N1(t),N2(t)]);
```

it gives the correct solution:

```
N1(t)=N0*exp(-l1*t)
N2(t)=N0*l1*exp(-l1*t)/(l2 - l1) - N0*l1*exp(-l2*t)/(l2 - l1)
```

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the denominator in the first answer - you have (l1 - l2), whereas in the second result you have (l2 - l1). The results are then the same - easy to miss though!

Comment: Thank you very much. You're right. The problem is that I was not evaluating the solution completely. I made a plot which was wrong. I've now found the reason for this. When I use the instruction  `eqns[0].rhs.subs({N0:1}) ` then it gives `l1*exp(-l2*t)/(l1 - l2) - l1*exp(-l1*t)/(l1 - l2) `. Guess I have to learn more about `subs` and why it changes the equation.